# Pygame lines disappear after rotating points

Tags: python, rotation, pygame

I am new to python and tried to make a game with a ship that rotates. However, after rotating, the ship disappears. I printed the coordinates of the three points, and the should appear on the screen. Does someone know what's wrong with my code?

This is the code for rotating the ship:

```
radius = self.width / 2
self.angle += da
center = [self.pos[0] + radius, self.pos[1] + radius]

for point in self.points:
    dx = int(math.cos(self.angle) * radius)
    dy = int(math.sin(self.angle) * radius)
    point[0] = center[0] + dx
    point[1] = center[1] + dy
```

This is the code for drawing the screen:

```
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        self.ship.move(self)
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        self.ship.rotate(0.08)
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        self.ship.rotate(-0.08)

    self.display.fill(self.bgcolor)
    self.ship.draw(self.display)

    pygame.display.update()
    self.fpsclock.tick(self.fps)
```

Comment: On a related note: don't modify the original coordinates with rotated versions. Due to numeric errors, your coordinates will drift & eventually become unusable. Instead, accumulate the rotation angle and position, and just translate/rotate before rendering, on a copy of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code:

```
for point in self.points:
    dx = int(math.cos(self.angle) * radius)
    dy = int(math.sin(self.angle) * radius)
    point[0] = center[0] + dx
    point[1] = center[1] + dy
```

Note that you're not using point for anything, just setting it. Assuming self.points is a list of the points that make up the ship, I think your ship is collapsing into a single point whenever it hits this code.